# Limit what is shown in the layer panel window under a categorized layer to that which is showing in the canvas extents in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, filter

I have imported a csv file via `'Open data source manager' > 'Delimited text'` which has multiple locations all specified with Eastings and Northings, these are plotted fine and in the layer styling panel I've categorized on a particular header from the csv template and styled accordingly. All works great, however I wanted to know if it was possible and how you would go about it if when you're zoomed in and say only 3 of the 12 locations within this layer are showing on the canvas/screen then only those three locations are displayed in the layer panel?

I know this can be achieved in the print manager via a checkbox setting but I wanted to apply the same functionality to the main 'working' environment too if it was possible...
[image: Example]

I'd only want the items circled in red showing when only these sites are in the canvas extent.

Bonus points for anyone who can tell me how I get the icons to be much smaller/not symbol in the layer list without affecting the object on the map canvas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `filter legend by map content` button.

Just be aware that it severely slows down QGIS if there are many features in the layers.

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's so simple. Can't believe it was there in front of me all along!

Comment: To be honest, I always see this icon as a shortcut to filter the data, not the legend...

Comment: Thanks, you're right it does slow down QGIS quite a bit. I'm guessing there's no way of applying that setting to just one or selected layers and have the other layers show in their entirety?

Comment: @MikeE not that I know unfortunately